# Mysql only loading one line of data

Tags: mysql

I am trying to load a tomcat access log into MySQL, to then do some reporting against it with Power Pivot.

The issue I am running into is it is only loading 1 line of data.  The fields match up to the table columns just fine, and it does not give me any errors on the import.

Sample data:

```
128.1.1.20 - - [03/Feb/2015:00:00:00 -0600] GET /isweb/servlet/PrintFilePollingServlet?id=248504470001111CC536F.ipf&version=2.01.01&pc=001111CC536F HTTP/1.1 200 45 - Java/1.7.0_40

128.1.1.243 - - [03/Feb/2015:00:00:00 -0600] GET /isweb/servlet/PrintFilePollingServlet?id=6967057597C0507ACC6EA.ipf&version=2.01.01&pc=7C0507ACC6EA HTTP/1.1 200 45 - Java/1.7.0_40
```

The table is all varchars with no primary keys or anything. It's also an innodb engine if that matters.  I will build the relations in the data in Power Pivot, just need the database to store it.  I would post a screen shot of it, but do not have enough rep points.

Query to load data:

```
load data infile '/tmp/sql/iweb.txt'
into table StandardGolfIweb
fields terminated by ' '
lines terminated by '\r\n';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each type of operating system uses a different line terminator.  Windows uses CRLF hex 0D 0A  escape seq \r\n.  Linux uses just the LF or \n.  Mac uses \r.

So your import statment never finds the end of line.  It fills up the first row space and drops the rest.

Change to lines terminated by '\n'; and see what happens.

Comment: I do not believe that is working properly either,  it give me an error that the data is to long for the field.  I increased the size of the varchar in that field.  It then gave me the error again in a field that cannot be that large farther down the file.  I dont think \n is defining the end of the file properly.  I should note that i did run this file through sed to remove all " out of the file.  I dont believe this should change the Line Feed though.

Comment: I took your two logfile lines and put them in a file on my linux server.  I created a mysql table  with 15 fields of varchar(200).  Then I ran the insert query using \n with no problems.  12 of the fields had info in them.

Comment: I am only seeing 12 fields in the data i posted.  Why did you make 15?

Comment: Just in case another split or two happened. It would avoid an error and point out that more was happening than you would think.   

Also, for some log entries, such as a stack trace, 200 characters will not be enough.  That might break it too.

Comment: i will give it a try,  did it only populate 12 of the fields?  This is a web access log so the location of the file it pulled should be the longest field in the logs.

Comment: I only got 12 fields from your posted log entries.

Comment: Interesting, I tried that and go an error that row 1 doesnt contain data for all columns,  Should i take away the Default NULL parameter?

Comment: Fixed it.  i needed to add ignore in front of the into table command.  this allowed me to load the data as advertised.  Something to do with Strict mode

Comment: Ah.  That is set in my.cnf or my.ini file.  There is innodb_strict_mode and sql_mode that don't allow some default behaviors and ignoring of minor errors.  

If it becomes too bothersome, valid values are on/off.  Change the setting and then restart the service.